# Как автоматически использовать DBUS в Linux-системах?

Tags: linux, cron, уведомления, systemd, dbus

У меня Debian. DBUS не работает автоматически, что бы я не делал. В данный момент пытаюсь просто отправить уведомление, используя notify-send. Что я пробовал к этому моменту:

```
#EnvironmentFile=/home/<user>/systemd/env.txt
#Environment=DISPLAY=:0
#Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/<user>/.Xauthority"
#Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

В разных комбинациях и способах. Но всегда возвращается одна и та же ошибка:

***sh[7297]: Невозможно автоматически запустить D-Bus без X11 $DISPLAY***

Comment: Для начала вам стоит определиться, *кому* вы хотите отправить уведомление, потому что понятия "просто ... в систему" в линуксе не существует

Comment: себе конечно...
для отладки пригодится.
"в систему" непонятно звучит - убрал

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, запускать notify-send нужно от имени конкретно того пользователя, который должен получить уведомление, иначе dbus не даст подключиться чужому пользователю. Вместе с этим прописывание DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS должно быть достаточно

Comment: То есть, например, в моём линуксе вполне работает команда вроде `USER=andreymal; sudo -u $USER DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path="$(loginctl show-user $USER -p RuntimePath --value)"/bus notify-send test`

Comment: `[Service]
User=<user>
Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh /home/z/systemd/hello.sh`

-- вот это решило проблему. Спасибо @andreymal

Answer (score 0):

Если программе не требуется особых разрешений и она работает в присутствии пользователя, то её лучше [запустить в сессии пользователя](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/User_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

Скрипт положить в `~/.config/systemd/user/` и включить `

```
systemctl --user enable hello.service
systemctl --user start hello.service
```

Таргет для установки

```
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```